# changing permalink causes 404 on visiting blog in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am changing permalink structure from

```
http://www.example.com/blog/index.php/2017/04/17/reasons-high-anxious-levels/
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/reasons-high-anxious-levels/
```

by going in settings>permalinks>change URL structure.

And on visiting to blog then it redirects me to 404 error page.
Please suggest how to achieve this

Comment: When you changed the permalink did it say it was successful or did it show you a message saying you needed to update your .htaccess? You may also need to check to make sure you have URL rewriting enabled in whatever server you're using.

Comment: It automatically saved the changes without showing any message. Please tell me how can I check if URL rewriting is enabled in server or not and how to enable this.

Comment: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`. But that's assuming you're using Apache on Ubuntu/Debian. Without knowing more about your setup, it will be difficult to answer.

Comment: Okay, I am using aws ec2. Let me check this and then I'll inform you

Answer (score 1):

You can use SEO Redirection for the url's you have changed. You can use the plugin 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-redirection/